# Git のマージ戦略 "resolve" とはどのような戦略ですか？

Tags: git, アルゴリズム

`git merge` のマージ戦略には `resolve` というものがあります。

> **resolve**
>   This can only resolve two heads (i.e. the current branch and another branch you pulled from) using a 3-way merge algorithm. It tries to carefully detect criss-cross merge ambiguities and is considered generally safe and fast.
>
> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies

この戦略はデフォルトの `recursive` と同じく 3-way merge のアルゴリズムを元にしているようなのですが、`recursive` と異なりどのようにして criss-cross マージの状況に対応しているのか良く分かりません。

`resolve` はどのようなアルゴリズムで criss-cross マージを処理しているのでしょうか？